# Periscope camera with a mobile phone, how to make walls not visible on the camera/alternative solution?

Tags: reflection, camera

I am trying to make like a "periscope" that i can use with a mobile camera. I have made a very quick prototype with two mirrors and it "works" but you can see the interior of the walls so it is not a good solution. It currently looks like this:
[image] [image]

So as I said the problem is that you can see the "walls" on the interior of the periscope when i put the camera in there. Is there anyway I can adjust this or do I need to look at an optional solution?

What i want to achieve is to make the backcamera of the phone to be like a frontcamera and have it under the camera that is vertical. (just like my current model). Can I somehow adjust the periscope (build it better, add more mirrors, maybe add a magnifying glass?) or do I need to build something else completely in order to make it work flawlessly without interior walls etc being in the way making the quality bad.

Any tips, tricks, links is very much appreciated!

Comment: Hello Carlos and welcome to physics stack exchange! This question seems to be more about engineering than physics, so I don't think it is on topic here. If you want to read more about what is on or off topic, you can check the help center. Thank you, though, for asking a well-formulated question!

Comment: I actually posted there before and then they said that i should post here instead. http://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11926/periscope-camera-with-a-mobile-phone-how-to-make-walls-not-visible-on-the-camer?noredirect=1#comment21123_11926 a bit confused right now haha. and thanks for the welcome :)

Comment: Hi Carlos, sorry I voted to close , but if engineeringSE think this is a physics problem, I suggest you rewrite it in the most "engineery" wording way you can, ( look at their most successful questions for ideas:), and resubmit it. It's optical engineering.

Comment: @CarlosRodrigez, I sure don't blame you for being confused. Try to follow CountTo10's advice and repost there; this really doesn't belong here. =)